# Do we consider the dual concept of the sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, logic, soft-question, category-theory

The concept of a sheaf on a topological space X can be veiwed as a projection from a topological E space to X which is a local homeomorphism (it belongs to the category of topological spaces).

What's the name of its dual concept and what are its applications?

Comment: I want to say that you are thinking of sections $\sigma:X\rightarrow E$.

Comment: There is a notion of cosheaf, but it is based on a different definition of sheaf.

Comment: However, we often fix a base X and discuss the category of total spaces on X, but rarely do it dually, right?

Comment: One, I don't think there is a dual notion to local homeomorphism. Two, the nerve-realization adjoint situation to the canonical functor Open$(X)\to \mathbf{Top}/X$ gives us sheaves as its fixed points. So if you wanted some kind of dual, maybe consider Open$(X)^{op}\to X/\mathbf{Top}$ which will give you an adjoint situation analogous to the one for sheaves, but giving you a subcategory of copresheaves $[\text{Open}(X),\mathbf{Set}]$.